# jQuery Flickrush - Wrapping <li> around the image

Tags: javascript, jquery, flickr

I have this div and unordered list:

```
<div id="flickr">
    <ul></ul>
</div>
```

I'm using this plugin - https://github.com/philipbeel/Flickrush

Here is the Javascript to make it work:

```
$(function() {
$("#flickr ul").flickrush({
    limit:20,
        id: "xxxxxxxx@xxx",
        random: false,
        ssl: true
}); 
});
```

Now it returns an `<img>` element only, but i need it to return a `<li><img></li>` for each result, as I have styled the `<li>` in a very specific way. I know it's [this file](https://github.com/philipbeel/Flickrush/blob/master/jquery.flickrush.js) i need to edit, but can't seem to figure out how to wrap the image in a list item. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace [lines 59-63](https://github.com/philipbeel/Flickrush/blob/master/jquery.flickrush.js#L59-L63):

```
flickrImage = $("<img/>").attr({
    src: item.media.m,
    alt: item.tags
});
```

with:

```
flickrImage = $('<li />').append(
    $("<img/>").attr({
        src: item.media.m,
        alt: item.tags
    })
);
```

This uses [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to append the `img` element to a newly created `li`.

Here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/33GVs/

Comment: Appreciate quick reply, doesn't work for some reason. still just returning the <img>. Any ideas?

Comment: @user2534723 - apologies for that, I just reversed it (so the `img` is being appended, not wrapped) and it's now working fine.

Comment: Works perfect, you are awesome!